# Force CakePHP plugin to use its own layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I have written a CakePHP plugin https://github.com/anuj9196/CakePHP-App-Installer

The plugin is using `default.ctp` layout from `plugin_path/src/template/layout/default.ctp`

When there is some other theme used in the host application. Like in my case I have setup one in `AppController`'s `beforeRender()`

```
$this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('DashboardTemplate');
```

`DashboardTemplate` is in application's `/plugin/` directory.

Now, when I access my plugin's URL using `example.com/installer/install`

The template loads on top of `DashboardTemplate` theme.

**How can I disable them in plugin's AppController?**

The `AppController` inside plugin directory contains

```
<?php
namespace Installer\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;

class AppController extends BaseController
{
    // nothing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the theme by using `beforeRender()` in your plugin's `AppController`.

```
<?php
namespace Installer\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;

class AppController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void
     */
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
         try {
             return parent::beforeRender($event);
         } finally {
             $this->viewBuilder()->setTheme(null);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between layouts in your view and controllers  fairly easily.. using plugin syntax

```
// inside controller 
  $this ->layout = 'Plugin.layout';

//inside view template
    $this ->layout = 'Plugin.layout';
```

If you just want to disable the theme, use Mathew's method above. But be careful that will disable the theme for the whole application not just this plugin in case some of your app code is ran after your plugin

Comment: Pretty sure that the syntax you've shown here is for some earlier version of CakePHP, not the 3.x series.